# how to solve this in javascript?

Tags: destructuring

````
> Locate the `displayBirthdate` function you initially defined, which took no parameter. Modify it to use object de-structuring to get just the 'dob' property of the parameter object it will receive

here's the code 
```javascript
const displayBirthdate = () => {};   
const displayAddress = () => {};  
const displayExtraUserInfo = (extra) => {  
    document.getElementById("btn-birthdate").addEventListener("click", ()=>   
        { displayBirthdate(extra) })
    document.getElementById("btn-phone").addEventListener("click", () => 
        { displayPhone(extra) }) 
    document.getElementById("btn-address").addEventListener("click", () => 
        { displayAddress(extra) })
```
````

adding to the above question
this is the expected response passed as parameter extra

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "gender": "female",
      "name": {
        "title": "ms",
        "first": "ceyhan",
        "last": "dizdar"
      },
      "location": {
        "street": "3826 şehitler cd",
        "city": "tekirdağ",
        "state": "bitlis",
        "postcode": 11689,
        "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "79.1017",
          "longitude": "27.1350"
        },
        "timezone": {
          "offset": "+5:45",
          "description": "Kathmandu"
        }
      },
      "email": "ceyhan.dizdar@example.com",
      "login": {
        "uuid": "34eb65b2-0535-4656-bd68-4da69dc6d016",
        "username": "orangefish864",
        "password": "grandpa",
        "salt": "vowzvAS2",
        "md5": "cf4a7f3210ef97e8e72defafd80b94c8",
        "sha1": "4f2af3439862b9bf25757ee73df8cd410ce201a2",
        "sha256": 
        "1497acbca446b5fa47d4bc5ffe4e82c17818176596b66d94f213f091c8ed8077"
      },
      "dob": {
        "date": "1979-08-10T22:03:55Z",
        "age": 39
      },
      "registered": {
        "date": "2008-05-24T13:30:20Z",
        "age": 10
      },
      "phone": "(873)-801-4132",
      "cell": "(751)-606-5317",
      "id": {
        "name": "",
        "value": null
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/59.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/59.jpg",
        "thumbnail": 
        "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/59.jpg"
      },
      "nat": "TR"
    }
  ],
  "info": {
    "seed": "008a9fe3a638239b",
    "results": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "version": "1.2"
  }
}
```

Now the question is this:
write an arrow function example displayBirthdate(), pass in this object(extra) as a parameter. using de-structuring method, grab the "dob" property in the object(extra). 
below is how i have attempted to solve the question:

```
const displayBirthdate = (obj) =>{
        const{results} = obj;
        const[{dob}] = results;
      }
```

but it appears to be incorrect. please any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Could you please be more explicit about your aim

Comment: What have been your tries so far? can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen here's the question:

Comment: Locate the displayBirthdate function you initially defined, which took no parameter. Modify it to use object de-structuring to get just the dob property of the parameter object it will receive.

Comment: here is the code

Comment: const displayBirthdate = () => {};
      
      
      const displayAddress = () => {};

Comment: const displayExtraUserInfo = (extra) => {
         document.getElementById("btn-birthdate").addEventListener("click", ()=> {
                displayBirthdate(extra)
            })
        
        document.getElementById("btn-phone").addEventListener("click", () => {
                displayPhone(extra)
            })
            document.getElementById("btn-address").addEventListener("click", () => {
                displayAddress(extra)
            })

Comment: Please edit the question to include the explicit code

Comment: i don't know, how i can edit the explicit code

Answer (score 0):

In your attempted solution, you were trying to obtain the `dob` object
from `results`, but `const{results} = obj;` evaluates `results` to 
an array. `const {dob} = results[0];` in my answer gets the `dob` object from the first element in the `results` array. Cheers!

```
const displayBirthdate = (obj) =>{
    const{results} = obj;
    const[{dob}] = results;
}
```

```
const displayBirthdate = (obj) =>{
    const {results} = obj;
    console.log(results); // this is an array with the required object at index = 0
    const {dob} = results[0];
    console.log(dob); // dob is the object you are looking for
}
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to OP's question, code only answers are discouraged on SO. Adding some context would help OP understand why this answer is sufficient, and it will help future visitor's to the site. Thanks!

Comment: @d_kennetz You are very right. I was looking at multiple questions so I quickly placed an answer here to move to another answer that's why I couldn't provide an explanation. I've added one now tho

Answer (score 0):

```
const displayBirthdate = ({dob}) => {};
const displayAddress ({location}) =>{};
```